# Programatically determine path to Chrome Extensions folder

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to programmatically determine the path to the Chrome Extensions folder? I want to make a call like the following:

```
xhr.open( 'GET', chrome.extension.getURL( '/' + msg.file ), true );
```

to consume the contents of a file I create with a native messaging host (so as to get past the 1MB pipe limitation for certain responses). I can *see* what my 'profiles' path is in chrome://version, but I cannot find anywhere where this might be exposed (was hoping, at the least, it could be exposed to extensions). Furthermore, there's a version subfolder that I do not know how it is constructed, e.g. I have the following subfolders for the Chrome Media Router extension:

5216.530.0.13_0
5216.530.0.14_0
5216.530.0.14_1

everything up to _ is the version from the manifest.json, but I don't know how/when the part after the _ comes into play (my guess is it is used to distinguish updates to the webstore when the version number is not changed).

so I really would most prefer an API function that would get me the full path for *my* extension from the extension.

Comment: There's no such API. Send your data in chunks.

Comment: OTOH, you can enumerate file handles of the parent process (e.g. on Windows via SystemHandleInformation) and get the profile path.

Comment: that is unfortunate, but thanks for the tip on enumerating the file handles...I may look into that.